# Authenticating a GCP service account using Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-iap

We are using Identity-Aware Proxy to secure our backend which is a REST API. For human users with a google account this works well so far.

I'm currently trying to connect another component to this API which is authenticating using a service account. Unfortunately the [documentation on this use case](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#obtaining_an_oidc_token_from_a_local_service_account_key_file) is a little bit sparse. I tried to adapt the example to the client ID of the OAuth client for this IAP.

```
def prepare_headers():
    open_id_connect_token = id_token.fetch_id_token(Request(), settings.backend.client_id)

    return {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {open_id_connect_token}'
    }
```

A service account key file is provided to the program using the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. Does anybody know how to obtain a working token using python?

Comment: Have you checked examples provided at the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/samples/iap-make-request) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/service-accounts-external-identities)?

Comment: Does `open_id_connect_token` actually contain an Identity Token (which is a base64 encoded JWT)? A common problem is that you must call a "refresh" method to actually get the token. Your code fragment is too small to know which libraries you are using. Create a minimum complete example.